# No idea where I'm getting NoSuchMethodError: '[]'

Tags: python, django, flutter, graphql

I am making a demo login app using python  framework-django, graphql, flutter like below.
[image]

This is a very simple app for a test but I'm getting "NoSuchMethodError='[]'", and I'm already spending a number of hours on this issue.

Error messages I am getting are below.

```
The user wants to create an account with dsafds@asdfasd.com and dasdfadsf dart_sdk.js:28087 
There was an error!
Uncaught (in promise) Error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: null
Arguments: [0]
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (:58141/dart_sdk.js:5348)
    at Object.defaultNoSuchMethod (:58141/dart_sdk.js:5793)
    at Object.noSuchMethod (:58141/dart_sdk.js:5788)
    at callNSM (:58141/dart_sdk.js:5521)
    at Object._checkAndCall (:58141/dart_sdk.js:5523)
    at Object.callMethod (:58141/dart_sdk.js:5601)
    at Object.dsend (:58141/dart_sdk.js:5604)
    at main._LoginPageState.new._createAccountPressed (:58141/packages/auth_frontend/main.dart.lib.js:1003)
    at _createAccountPressed.next (<anonymous>)
    at :58141/dart_sdk.js:39230
    at _RootZone.runUnary (:58141/dart_sdk.js:39087)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue (:58141/dart_sdk.js:34073)
    at handleValueCallback (:58141/dart_sdk.js:34633)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (:58141/dart_sdk.js:34671)
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (:58141/dart_sdk.js:34513)
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback (:58141/dart_sdk.js:34536)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (:58141/dart_sdk.js:39374)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (:58141/dart_sdk.js:39380)
    at :58141/dart_sdk.js:34887
```

Flutter doctor result is below

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19043.1165], locale en-US)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.60.0)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

My flutter project code is below (I excluded unimportant lines)
<main.dart>

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';
import 'graphql_config.dart';
import 'graphql_query.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(
    GraphQLProvider(
      client: GraphQLConfiguration.initializeClient(),
      child: CacheProvider(child: MyApp()),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'My first Django plus Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: LoginPage(),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

enum FormType { login, register }

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  GraphQLConfiguration graphQLConfiguration = GraphQLConfiguration();
  QueryMutation addMutation = QueryMutation();

  final TextEditingController _emailFilter = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordFilter = TextEditingController();

  String _email = "";
  String _password = "";
  FormType _form = FormType.login;

  _LoginPageState() {
    _emailFilter.addListener(_emailListen);
    _passwordFilter.addListener(_passwordListen);
  }

  void _emailListen() {
    if (_emailFilter.text.isEmpty) {
      _email = "";
    } else {
      _email = _emailFilter.text;
    }
  }

  void _passwordListen() {
    if (_passwordFilter.text.isEmpty) {
      _password = "";
    } else {
      _password = _passwordFilter.text;
    }
  }
  ....
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Python & Flutter Login by Hong"),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            _buildTextFields(),
            _buildButtons(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTextFields() {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _emailFilter,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email'),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              controller: _passwordFilter,
              decoration: InputDecoration(labelText: 'Password'),
              obscureText: true,
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildButtons() {
    if (_form == FormType.login) {
      return Container(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Login'),
            onPressed: _loginPressed,
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Don have an account? Tap here to register'),
            onPressed: _formChange,
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Forgot Password?'),
            onPressed: _passwordReset,
          ),
        ],
      ));
    } else {
      return Container(
          child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Create an Account'),
            onPressed: _createAccountPressed,
          ),
          TextButton(
            child: Text('Don have an account? Tap here to login'),
            onPressed: _formChange,
          ),
        ],
      ));
    }
  }
  ...
  void _createAccountPressed() async {
    print('The user wants to create an account with $_email and $_password');
    GraphQLClient _client = graphQLConfiguration.clientToQuery();
    QueryResult result = await _client.mutate(
      MutationOptions(
        // ignore: deprecated_member_use
        document: addMutation.register('$_email', '', '$_password'),
      ),
    );
    if (result.data["success"] != null) {
      print('The user was created successfully!');
    } else {
      print('There was an error!');
      print(result.data["register"]["errors"]["email"][0]["message"]);
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

<graphql_config.dart>

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:graphql_flutter/graphql_flutter.dart';
// ignore: import_of_legacy_library_into_null_safe
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class GraphQLConfiguration {
  static final HttpLink httpLink = HttpLink(
    uri: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/graphql",
  );

  static final AuthLink authLink = AuthLink(getToken: () async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return pref.getString("token");
  });

  static final Link link = authLink.concat(httpLink);

  static ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> initializeClient() {
    ValueNotifier<GraphQLClient> client = ValueNotifier(
      GraphQLClient(
        link: link,
        cache: OptimisticCache(dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject),
      ),
    );
    return client;
  }

  GraphQLClient clientToQuery() {
    return GraphQLClient(
      link: link,
      cache: OptimisticCache(dataIdFromObject: typenameDataIdFromObject),
    );
  }
}
```

<graphql_query.dart>

```
class QueryMutation {
  String register(String email, String user, String password) {
    return """ 
      mutation {
        register(
          email: "$email",
          username: "$user",
          password1: "$password",
          password2: "$password",
        ) {
          success,
          errors,
          token,
          refreshToken
        }
      }
    """;
  }
}
```

<settings.py - django>

```
"""
Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.7.
...
"""

from pathlib import Path

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'users',
    'graphene_django',
    'graphql_jwt.refresh_token.apps.RefreshTokenConfig',
    "graphql_auth",
    'django_filters',
    'corsheaders',
]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

GRAPHENE = {
    'SCHEMA': 'auth2.schema.schema', # this file doesn't exist yet
    'MIDDLEWARE': [
        'graphql_jwt.middleware.JSONWebTokenMiddleware',
    ],
}

GRAPHQL_JWT = {
    "JWT_VERIFY_EXPIRATION": True,
 
    # optional
    "JWT_LONG_RUNNING_REFRESH_TOKEN": True,

    "JWT_ALLOW_ANY_CLASSES": [
        "graphql_auth.mutations.Register",
    ],
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    # 'graphql_jwt.backends.JSONWebTokenBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    "graphql_auth.backends.GraphQLAuthBackend",
]

EMAIL_BACKEND ='django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

ROOT_URLCONF = 'auth2.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'auth2.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        ...
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    ...
]
...
```

I'm assuming there is something wrong with async/await things but I am not too sure about it.
I've been trying a number of ways, but it seems like it's even getting more complicated.

Any advice would highly be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you made a typo in main.dart here and you should go into your map like this:

```
if ((result.data["mutation"])["success"] != null) {
...
}
```

it should be success not sucess.

Also, for accessing maps you should be aware to use parenthesis when neccessary:

```
print((((((result.data["register"])["errors"])["email"])[0])["message"]));
```

Comment: Thanks so much for telling me that. Silly mistake. But It still doesn't work after getting that fixed TT

Comment: Comment out this part and see if the error goes away:       print(result.data["register"]["errors"]["email"][0]["message"]);

Comment: Still, the same error but I can see [success] ... I am sure new users are successfully registered but just NoSuchMethod error keeps on coming out, =>  The user wants to create an account with dsasdf@dsafds.com and dafsdfads. username is dsasdf
Error: NoSuchMethodError: '[]'
Dynamic call of null.
Receiver: null
Arguments: ["success"]
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:52989/dart_sdk.js:5348:11)
    ....

Comment: do it like this: (result.data["mutation "])["success"];

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem until I added Cors and it worked for me

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
)
```